# CSS objects in div move when hovering

Tags: html, css, hover, icons

I am currently helping out a friend by adding social media icons to his website. I wanted to use a cool hovering effect, but when I hover the icons, they'll move inside the `div`. It's not very surprising, but I couldn't find any other way than adjusting the padding so it looks like they don't move. It doesn't look really decent and is kind of cheaty.

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/a63c918c5b.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

<style media="screen" type="text/css">
  .icons {
    position: relative;
    padding: 9px;
  }
  .icons:hover {
    color: #4f5255;
    font-size: 19px;
    transition: font-size 0.2s;
    /*padding: 7px;*/
  }
  div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
  }
</style>

<div>
  <a target="_blank" href="link" class="icons fa fa-facebook" style="color: #4f5255;text-decoration:none;"></a>
  <a target="_blank" href="link" class="icons fa fa-twitter" style="color: #4f5255;text-decoration:none"></a>
  <a target="_blank" href="link" class="icons fa fa-instagram" style="color: #4f5255;text-decoration:none"></a>
</div>
```

I don't want the icons to move horizontally and vertically when hovering over one of the icons. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't transition the font-size. Use `scale()`. This will not effect surrounding elements.

If you move the `transition` to the default state, rather the the `:hover` state you won't get that "snap" back to the default size.

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/a63c918c5b.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

<style media="screen" type="text/css">
  .icons {
    position: relative;
    padding: 9px;
    transition: transform 0.2s;
  }
  .icons:hover {
    color: #4f5255;
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
  }
</style>



<div>
  <a target="_blank" href="link" class="icons fa fa-facebook" style="color: #4f5255;text-decoration:none;"></a>
  <a target="_blank" href="link" class="icons fa fa-twitter" style="color: #4f5255;text-decoration:none"></a>
  <a target="_blank" href="link" class="icons fa fa-instagram" style="color: #4f5255;text-decoration:none"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't forget to use prefixes because it will significantlly lower your browser compatibillity. Here is the link http://caniuse.com/#search=scale